# Resizing Content to fit the Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have a grid containing a content (custom shape).

I saw a lot of posts saying how to make the grid automatically fit the content. But is it possible to make the content resize to automatically fit the grid as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Viewbox

```
 <Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <Path Data="M 0 0 L 10 0 L 10 10 Z" Fill="RoyalBlue"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```